# Is there an easier way to share file descriptors between unrelated processes on modern day Linux (i.e., ver>=3.0.0)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

Does Linux provide a better way to send an fd from one process to another, for sharing, than using a `sendmsg()` syscall to send it (a message with type set to `SCM_RIGHTS`) over a UNIX Domain socket? I guess the best possibility would be to somehow be able to name an fd and then open it (by name) in an unrelated process, but I am open to other alternatives.

The reason I am asking this question is to be able to use the *fd() functions (e.g., `eventfd()`, `timerfd()`, `signalfd()`, etc...) between processes with no parent-child relationship, making it much more difficult to share file descriptors.

Comment: No, `sendmsg` is *the* way to pass file descriptors. It's not that difficult actually.

Comment: Imagine this, I have a single server and many clients. I now need to have a UNIX domain socket on the server process and I also need the same on each client process. Then, on say client startup, after this unix domain socket is set up on the client and the connection is accepted by the server, I need to coordinate the passing of the fd from the server to the client, before the client can continue with other processing. This is a hell of a lot more complex than the client opening an object like it can with a POSIX named IPC.

Comment: Hmm, not too much different from any other socket programming. One process listens for unix connections and sends out your event fd(s) (you can't really pass signal fds around, timers - maybe, but I never tried), each client connects and grabs the event fd. Wrap that into couple of functions and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library to do this for you at [https://www.normalesup.org/~george/comp/libancillary/](https://www.normalesup.org/%7Egeorge/comp/libancillary/) which is used in a number of projects by copying into their tree, but the primary git host is no longer alive.